# Check for expiration by calculating the number of days between given dates MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix-timestamp

In my project I need the user subscribed plans which are not expired. When a user subscribe to a plan, it will be entered in a table *usersubscription* with structure as shown below:

```
id  user_id   plan_id  subscribed_on
```

The table for storing plan details is *subscription_plans*:

```
id  plan   days_limit  discounted_rate  added_on    status  rate
1   PlanJ  30          240              1403094260  1       245.00
```

What I need is to check whether user has subscribed to a plan (containing selected video) which is not expired (ie,it will expire on *subscribed_on+days_limit* day). The current query which I am using now is

```
select id from usersubscription where (plan_id 
        IN 
        (
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT plan_id 
            FROM 
            subscribed_videos sv where sv.videoid = 2
          )
        )
       OR id IN 
      (
           SELECT DISTINCT assosiated_plan_id AS plan_id
           FROM subscription_groups sg
           JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id
           WHERE sv.videoid = 2
       )
    ) and user_id=1
```

This will check whether a user with id 1 is subscribed to any plans containing video with id 2. I am saving date as integer (unix timestamp).

Can anyone help me to find a solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you build schema on MySql [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @Shell..Please check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f734/1

Comment: I don't know will it help or not. But, I have tried. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df9619/1/2

Comment: @Shell..What I need is to check whether there is active plan for selected video (ie, not expired plans). The query should return empty rows or records if it satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select us.id from usersubscription us INNER JOIN subscription_plans sp ON us.plan_id = sp.id
 where (us.plan_id IN 
        (
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT plan_id 
            FROM 
            subscribed_videos sv where sv.videoid = 2
          )
        )
       OR us.id IN 
      (
           SELECT DISTINCT assosiated_plan_id AS plan_id
           FROM subscription_groups sg
           JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id
           WHERE sv.videoid = 2
       )
    )   and us.user_id=1 
        and sp.subscribed_on > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL (sp.days_limit * -1) DAY))
```

This will returns record which subscription is still active.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from usersubscription us
JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id
where (plan_id 
    IN 
    (
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT plan_id 
        FROM 
        subscribed_videos sv where sv.videoid = 2
      )
    )
   OR id IN 
  (
       SELECT DISTINCT assosiated_plan_id AS plan_id
       FROM subscription_groups sg
       JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id
       WHERE sv.videoid = 2
   )
) and user_id=1
and FROM_UNIXTIME(us.date) < TIMESTAMPADD(day,sv.days_limit,FROM_UNIXTIME(us.date))
```